# update a row with id generated by (auto increment)

Tags: php, mysql

am kind of confuse how to go about with this ,i have a table called post with column id............ post_id,what am trying to do is to update the post_id with the id,that if id is=1 post_id will be =1 too,here is my code so far

```
<?php
$usernme = ($_POST['test']);

$id = $_SESSION['elchAppXD'];

$ac = 1;

$queryNewPlege = "INSERT INTO posts (text, timeline_id, active) VALUES ('$usernme', '$id', '$ac')";

if (mysqli_query($dbhandle, $queryNewPlege)) {
    $upQuery = "UPDATE posts SET post_id = id";
}
// echo "i";
// if($_SESSION['Role'] == 4)
{

}
?>
```

here is the line of code that was suppose to update it but am confuse,as i don't know how to get the id and reinsert it in post_id   `$upQuery = "UPDATE posts SET post_id = id";`.please any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: you are not executing your query like `mysqli_query($dbhandle, $upQuery )`. are you ?

Answer (score 1):

That update query will be,

```
  $updateId = $mysqli->insert_id;
  $upQuery = "UPDATE posts SET post_id = $updateId where id = $updateId";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last insert id using this `mysqli_insert_id`

```
if(mysqli_query($dbhandle,$queryNewPlege)){

    $getLastInsertID = mysqli_insert_id($dbhandle)

    $upQuery = "UPDATE posts SET post_id = getLastInsertID";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this :

```
$queryNewPlege = "INSERT INTO posts (text, timeline_id, active) VALUES ('$usernme', '$id', '$ac')";

if (mysqli_query($dbhandle, $queryNewPlege)) {
    $id = $mysqli->insert_id;
    $upQuery = "UPDATE posts SET post_id =".$id."WHERE id=".$id;
}
```